# Creating multiple(26) buttons in one layout screen

Tags: java, android, xml, button, layout

Trying to create a simple ABCs and 123s app. My initial layout has two buttons, 1 for alphabet and one for numbers. If alphabet button is clicked, I want to go to the next fragment which would hold 26 buttons for all alphabet (A-Z). For numbers, 10 buttons (0-9). MY question is, how do i efficiently populate a layout file with 26 buttons/10 buttons without writing each one of them in the XML file?

Comment: You could you as grid layout and lay the buttons.

Comment: @lsiva As much as we expect users to write clear questions, we should also expect clear answers and comments. That... doesn't make any sense. 
OP, you might want to show us what code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use gridview

activity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:columnWidth="90dp"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"
/>
```

your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
      gridview.setAdapter(new GridAdapter (this));
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
   }
}
```

gridView adapter

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   private Context mContext;

   // Constructor
   public GridAdapter (Context c) {
      mContext = c;
   }

   public int getCount() {
      return alphabets.length;
   }

   public Object getItem(int position) {
      return null;
   }

   public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
   }

   // create a new TextView for each item referenced by the Adapter
   public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      TextView txView;

      if (convertView == null) {
         txView= new TextView (mContext);
         txView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
         txView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
      } 
      else 
      {
         txView= (TextView) convertView;
      }
      txView.setText(alphabets[position]);

       **Update**
       txView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
            //your code here
               switch(position){
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(this,"A",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(this,"B",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
                ........SoOn
               }

           }});


      return txView;
   }

   //  array
   public String[] alphabets= {
      "A","B","C","D"
   };
}
```

Comment: I was able to implement that and make them 26 buttons. But I have two questions, 1) the size of the buttons are small and I cant seem to change their size, 2) how would I add onClickListeners to all of those buttons?

Comment: txView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));//change the width,height here.. View the updated answer, please accept the answer if this helped

Comment: How does the one onClickListener work for all of the buttons? Won't I need one for each letter/number? Because I want each button to go to a separate letter but they should all be sort of connected because it'll be a viewpager. Also, thanks a lot for your help, what do you mean accept the answer? (I think I have too few reputation to do it)

Comment: Edited my answer try it

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically add buttons to a view. Try this in your onCreateView function of you fragment.

```
//mView is your fragment root, and container is defined in XML
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)mView.findViewById(R.id.alpha_container)

String[] letters = {A, B, C, ..., Z};

for(int i=0; i<letters.length; i++) { 
   Button letter_btn = new Button(getActivity());
   letter.setText(letters[i]);
   container.addView(letter_btn, i);
}
```

This will programmatically create a button for each element in the letters array. You can attach onClickListener(s) accordingly and track the buttons by text content or give them a tag/id.

Comment: What would I have to include in the layout file for that fragment? A framelayout, recyclerview? Anything?

Comment: A LinearLayout, (or any ViewGroup really), will be sufficient.

Comment: If you are looking for a robust feature set, (such as adding and removing buttons and handling many events), i would recommend using a view with an adapter, (e.g. GridView/Listview). @SaravInfern's answer is perfectly acceptable